# How do I stop pre-commit on failure?

Tags: git, pre-commit.com

I have two `git` pre-commit hooks enabled in `pre-commit-config.yml`:

1. A code formatting hook that takes very little time
2. Our pytest hook, which takes much more time

When (1) updates code formatting, it fails, but (2) still runs. Then (1) and (2) must be run again, doubling the time it takes to run the commit. I'd rather run (1) and run (2) only if (1) passes. Is that possible using `pre-commit`, and if so, how would I do it? I've plumbed the depths fo the documentation but so far I've been unable to find anything useful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would not recommend having slow checks in pre-commit, you're likely to have your developers disable / ignore it / context switch

that said, there's an option specifically designed for this, the [`fail_fast`](https://pre-commit.com/#top_level-fail_fast) option

it's a top level option so you'd set it like this:

```yaml
fail_fast: true

repos:
# ...
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit